# Problem with pointer conversion using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

My project is using [Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), and I'm trying to use the following Accessibility API function:

```
extern AXError AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue (
    AXUIElementRef element,
    CFStringRef attribute,
    CFTypeRef *value);
```

To call the function, I'm doing something like this:

```
NSArray *subElements = nil;
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(..., (CFArrayRef *)&subElements);
```

However, ARC is throwing the following error regarding the last argument:

```
error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'CFArrayRef *' (aka 'const struct __CFArray **') is disallowed with ARC
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The tools that work with ARC are still under NDA. You should post questions like this in [Apple's developer forums.](https://devforums.apple.com)

Comment: @Rob: not technically true; the ARC compiler is a new version of LLVM, LLVM is open source and the changes have already been committed. The whole thing is fully documented already at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html (though from a compiler and grammar point of view; I'm sure whatever Apple supply will be more friendly).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried using an intermediate CFArrayRef, so that you can still pass a pointer to a ref (ie, a pointer to a pointer) to `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue`, but can then achieve the toll-free bridge with just an ordinary cast? E.g.

```
CFArrayRef subElementsCFArray;
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(..., &subElementsCFArray);

NSArray *subElements = (__bridge NSArray *)subElementsCFArray;
```

Comment: Your theory was correct, but the implementation was wrong. I've updated your answer for code that will actually compile with ARC. Thanks!

Comment: IMHO you does not transfer the ownership to ARC therefore you have to release the CFArrayRef here. If you use (__bridge_transfer NSArray *) you can skip that.